# Input Celsius/Fahrenheit then convert

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

So I'm writing a c++ code that should ask a user whether they want to use Celsius or Fahrenheit, then ask them the degrees, then convert it. My program won't compile, with the complaint that the compiler expects an identifier and that I'm missing a ; before char is identified. Please tell me exactly what's wrong with my code in detail. Please keep in mind that I am new and any information is greatly appreciated, yet I won't understand more complex terminology/code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char 'C';
double degree;
int degree_type;


cout << "What's the Degree type?: ";
cin >> degree_type;


if (degree_type == 'C')
{

cout << "What's the Temperature?: ";
cin >> degree; 

cout << degree << " degrees Celsius is = " << 9 / 5 * degree + 32 << " Degrees Fahrenheit" << endl;

}

else
{
cout << "What's the Temperature?: ";
cin >> degree;

cout << degree << " degrees Fahrenheit is = " << (degree - 32) * 5/9 << " Degrees Celsius" << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char 'C';` is meaningless. Remove it.

Comment: Okay, in doing so I can cout the result, which is great, but it won't let me cin the variable degree. Why not?

Comment: Call `cin.ignore();` after the first `cin` to clear the newline from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove char 'C' and change type for "degree_type" to char , something like this.

```
//char 'C'; Comment this line or remove
double degree;
char degree_type; // change this
```

Comment: This fix worked perfectly, thanks so much for the help. I finally understand where and how to use char effectively. Thanks again for helping and putting up with me!